# Network Error - 53 when Mounting Azure Blob storage using NFS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, mount, nfs

I followed below notes to mount the blob storage.

Workflow and support notes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support

Instructions on Mounting blob: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support-how-to?tabs=windows

> The Storage account is enabled with NFS, the storage account is created after "AllowNSF3" is registered

[image]

> The Storage account is created after NFS3.0 enabled as mentioned in
> the doc

[image]

> The Storage account is configured to selected networks with virtual
> network

[image]

- Configured Virtual network gateway for my virtual gateway
- Configured Point-to-site configuration to Connect to a my VNet using P2S VPN & certificate authentication

> Firewall outbound ports(both UDP and TCP) 111, 2048, 2049 are open on
> client computer

[image]

- The client computer downloaded VPN client and connected to VNet

> No firewall configured on my VNet

[image]

When I try to mount using following command, I am getting **Network Error - 53**

```
C:\Windows\system32>mount -o nolock mycloudstorage1.blob.core.windows.net:/mycloudstorage1/myblobcontainer *
Network Error - 53

Type 'NET HELPMSG 53' for more information.
```

Not sure how to troubleshoot this further, any **trace error logs** to know more about this error?

Comment: Is that you mount the blob from on-premise network?

Comment: Could you please provide the firewall of the account?

Comment: @JimXu Yes I am trying to mount from the on-premise network that is connected via p2s VPN. and No firewall yet configured on virtual network.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you can access azure blob in the browser with your VPN?

Comment: @JimXu i get Resource inot found error when try to access via browser:
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:2019af98-601e-001c-1090-09fd0a000000 Time:2021-02-23T03:00:19.5431020Z</Message>
</Error>

Comment: Hi. According to my research, after we enable vnet projection fro blob storage, we need to access blob storage via the service endpoint. But we cannot use the p2s VPN to route traffic from on-premises to service endpoint. we need to need to add our public IP in firewall.  For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview#secure-azure-service-access-from-on-premises and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/virtual-network-service-endpoints-and-firewalls-for-azure-storage-now-generally-available/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and came to find out.

- If you have selected Standard performance you have to choose one of the following regions: Australia East, Korea Central, and South Central US.

Comment: @JuanCalos If you see my storage account configuration the "NFS V3" is enabled. This option will not be enabled if you don't choose option that it mentioned in Step 5 in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support-how-to?tabs=windows hence your suggestion is not valid

Comment: Does your VNET have the same address spaces as your on-premise address spaces? If so. I would think that would be routing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a private endpoint for the storage account and adding the PEP ip to the hosts file on the endpoint you would like to mount the NFS container to see the steps below.

In your storage account settings go to private endpoint connections click + Private endpoint
[image1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eRNp.png)

Select the appropriate resource group and name the Private endpoint. Click through to the next section
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUYQw.png)

Select blob as the Target sub-resource. Click through to the next section
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92J3s.png)

Select the vnet and subnet associated with the storage account. Select yes to integrate with private DNS zone. Click review and create.
[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5fYu.png)

Once the private endpoint has been created you will need to get the ip address that is associated with the Private endpoint nic. Navigate back to the networking pane of the storage account and click back into the Private endpoint connections. Click the newly created Private endpoint.
[image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvegp.png)

Click on the nic located next to the network interface field.
[image6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXOpk.png)

The copy the Private IP address.
[image7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym22R.png)

On your Windows endpoint edit your hosts file this can be done many ways the easiest is to open an admin elevated instance of notepad. Navigate to the hosts file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc enter the Private IP address and address of the storage account as shown below and save.
[image8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioqz6.png)

If the vnet subnet you selected to associate with the private endpoint is not already added to the storage account make sure to do so. The storage container should be able to be mounted as a NFS share in windows.